# SPI - RX and TX alternative names for MISO and MOSI?

Tags: spi

In all datasheets up until now I have only seen `MISO` and `MOSI` in use as SPI data line identifiers. However the datasheet of an automotive microcontroller refers to these lines as `SPI_TXD` and `SPI_RXD`.

I'd assume that this is just a different naming convention and the following is true:

- `MISO` = `SPI_RXD`
- `MOSI` = `SPI_TXD`

Unfortunately I cannot provide a link to the datasheet as it is not publicly available.

###### Question

Is this correct, provided that we're looking from the uController (i.e. Master) side?

Comment: Is this in the pinout description? On a device pin it's usually as seen from that device (at least that's the case for the RP2040). So a pin named RX would be MISO on a controller and MOSI on a peripheral. On a connector I would say there is no convention.

Comment: The answer will be in datasheet itself. There can be no generic answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to refer to MOSI and MISO as "Rx" or "Tx" unless you do so from a certain node's viewpoint. The naming is senseless - MOSI and MISO are great names since they eliminate the whole tx rx brainfart terminology that we see in for example UART-based buses. Tx and Rx of what, is it a modem, is it a terminal, is it semi-duplex. Sigh. Anyone wanna play a game? I pay you a dollar for each time I mixed up MISO with MOSI and then you pay me a dollar for each time I mixed up Tx and Rx of UART-based buses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MISO stands for **M**aster **I**nput, **S**lave **O**utput.
MOSI stands for **M**aster **O**utput, **S**lave **I**nput.

As data is received (RX) on the input and data is sent (transmitted, TX) on the output, from the master's point of view, MISO is its RX pin and MOSI is its TX pin, so:
`MISO` = `SPI_RXD`
`MOSI` = `SPI_TXD`

(For a slave, this would be reversed)

Answer (score 4):

MOSI is the name of the wire between master-out (transmit) and slave-in (receive).

- So you have master.tx pin -> MOSI wire -> slave.rx pin.

MISO is the name of the wire between slave-out (transmit) and master-in (receive).

- So you have slave.tx pin -> MISO wire -> master.tx pin.

A microcontroller could be a SPI master or SPI slave.  This determines which pins connect to the MOSI and MISO wires.

If the microcontroller is a SPI master (which is likely if the other SPI device(s) are sensors), then its SPI_TXD pin will drive the MOSI wire, and its SPI_RXD pin will receive from the MISO wire.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct.  Also, you may run into `SOMI` & `SIMO`.  
Why the manufactures insist on changing a standard name is beyond me.

Comment: The root of the problem is that there exists no ISO/IEC standard for SPI.